# Sort repeating numbers numerically

Tags: python, algorithm, list, sorting

Given a list of values, like the following:

```
n = [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3]
```

What is the fastest way to sort such list as:

```
y = [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2]
```

In other words, I would like the values grouped so that the first occurrences of the values appear first, the second appearances second, and so on, with the numbers sorted by value within the groups.

Comment: how would you sort `n = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4,5]

Comment: You need a key to actually be sorting on--why is that the order?

Comment: you need to clarify. do all numbers have the same fixed count? also are they consecutive?

Comment: could it possibly be reworded as 'grouping and sorting consecutive numbers[, with sorted trailing outliers]'?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you want to group the values into `n` groups, where group `n` contains all the `n`th occurrences of each value, and then to sort by value within the groups. This does that:

```
>>> import collections
>>> def scan_count(l):
...     count = collections.defaultdict(int)
...     for i in l:
...         yield count[i]
...         count[i] += 1
... 
>>> l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
>>> [b for a, b in sorted(zip(scan_count(l), l))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> l = [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> [b for a, b in sorted(zip(scan_count(l), l))]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3]
```

I'm not sure it's the fastest; an in-place sort might be faster, but this gives you the basic idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a list of alternate values, this will do it:

```
n = sorted(n) # optionally sort n
n[0::2] + n[1::2]
```

Comment: This isn't much different from say `n[::2] * 2`. I think there isn't a clear enough generalization of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sorted_n = sorted(n)
>>> list_of_lists = [sorted_n [i:i+2] for i in range(0,len(sorted_n),2)]
>>> list(itertools.chain(*zip(*list_of_lists)))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

maybe ... not sure if its the fastest also it may not work how you expect if you dont have very simillar values to what you put as n in your question

Answer (score 0):

I propose an algorithm that:

- given a sorted list of integers in non decreasing order
- returns the same list sorted such that integers are non decreasing and whenever possible consecutive integers are different
- it is in place and liner in time (it scans twice the input list)
- it is not specific to python
- it handles missing numbers

**Examples**

```
input =  [0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2]
output = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]

input =  [0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
output = [0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4]
```

**What it does**

Each time it encounter a new elements (here an integer) it remembers it and
it counts the number of occurrences it appears in the input.

Then it consecutively writes on the original input one occurrence of each element until the list is full.

I also wrote an other version inspired by the flag problem (so with a list of index where to insert the elements) but it is not better than this and maybe a bit less clear.

Nothing better came to my mind doh...

**The Algorithm**

```
def my_sort(ari):
   #check if there is something to sort..
   if len(ari) < 1:
    return ari

   #initialize vars..
   elements = [ari[0]]  #list of found elements
   occurences = [1]      #occurence[i-th] stores the number of occurrences found for the elements[i-th]
   i = 1

   while(i < len(ari)):
      if (ari[i] != elements[len(elements)-1]):
         occurences.append(1)
         elements.append(ari[i])
      else:
         occurences[len(occurences)-1] += 1
      i +=1

   k = 0

   while(k < len(ari)):
      for i in range(len(elements)):
         if occurences[i] > 0:
            ari[k] = elements[i]
            occurences[i] = occurences[i] - 1
            k += 1

   return ari

asd = [0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4]
print my_sort(asd)
```